# How to use flowtype with cdn included objects?

Tags: vue.js, flowtype

I'd like to use flowtype to check some Vue codes, the vue is included:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

and the js code:

```
//@flow
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
})
```

but flowtype will report error, how to deal with this kind of error:

```
var app = new Vue({
               ^^^ identifier `Vue`. Could not resolve name
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, neither official Vue.js or flow-typed has official Flowtype definitions for Vue.js.

So, it looks like the following line is a quick fix:

```
declare var Vue:any
```